# Error message on example flink job: Unable to make field private final byte[] java.lang.String.value accessible

Tags: apache-flink

I am getting started with Apache Flink. I will post the error I encountered and then steps to reproduce it

This is the command I ran-

`./bin/flink run examples/streaming/WordCount.jar --input`

This is the error text-

```
org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: The main method caused an error: Unable to make field private final byte[] java.lang.String.value accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @3c60b7e7
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:372)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.invokeInteractiveModeForExecution(PackagedProgram.java:222)
    at org.apache.flink.client.ClientUtils.executeProgram(ClientUtils.java:114)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.executeProgram(CliFrontend.java:812)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.run(CliFrontend.java:246)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.parseAndRun(CliFrontend.java:1054)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.lambda$main$10(CliFrontend.java:1132)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.contexts.NoOpSecurityContext.runSecured(NoOpSecurityContext.java:28)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.main(CliFrontend.java:1132)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private final byte[] java.lang.String.value accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @3c60b7e7
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:172)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner.clean(ClosureCleaner.java:106)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner.clean(ClosureCleaner.java:132)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner.clean(ClosureCleaner.java:69)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.clean(StreamExecutionEnvironment.java:2138)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.addSource(StreamExecutionEnvironment.java:1818)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.createFileInput(StreamExecutionEnvironment.java:1735)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.readFile(StreamExecutionEnvironment.java:1522)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.readTextFile(StreamExecutionEnvironment.java:1326)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.readTextFile(StreamExecutionEnvironment.java:1297)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.examples.wordcount.WordCount.main(WordCount.java:69)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:355)
    ... 8 more
```

These are the steps to reproduce the error

> 1- I installed the Java JDK version 17.0.2 [here](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/)
>
> 2- I installed Maven version 3.8.4 [here](https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi)
>
> 3- I downloaded the file called "flink-1.14.3-bin-scala_2.12.tgz"
> [here](https://archive.apache.org/dist/flink/flink-1.14.3/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the wrong version of Java installed. I had Java 17.x instead of Java 11.x.

After I installed Java 11.x, the job successfully runs.