# Failing Apache Beam Pipeline when consuming events through KafkaIO on Flink runner

Tags: java, apache-flink, apache-beam, apache-beam-kafkaio

I have a beam pipeline with several stages that consumes data through a KafkaIO and the code looks like below,

```
pipeline.apply("Read Data from Stream", StreamReader.read())
        .apply("Decode event and extract relevant fields", ParDo.of(new DecodeExtractFields()))
        .apply(...);
```

`StreamReader.read()` method implementation,

```
public static KafkaIO.Read<String, String> read() {
    return KafkaIO.<String, String>read()
            .withBootstrapServers(Constants.BOOTSTRAP_SERVER)
            .withTopics(Constants.KAFKA_TOPICS)
            .withConsumerConfigUpdates(Constants.CONSUMER_PROPERTIES)
            .withKeyDeserializer(StringDeserializer.class)
            .withValueDeserializer(StringDeserializer.class)
  //Line-A  .withMaxReadTime(Duration.standardDays(10))
            .withLogAppendTime();
}
```

When running the pipeline on the **Direct Runner**, it runs without throwing any errors.
But in my case, I have to use the **Flink Runner** and when the pipeline runs on the **Flink Runner**, it throws the following error,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while translating UnboundedSource: org.apache.beam.sdk.io.kafka.KafkaUnboundedSource@14b31e37
    at org.apache.beam.runners.flink.FlinkStreamingTransformTranslators$UnboundedReadSourceTranslator.translateNode(FlinkStreamingTransformTranslators.java:250)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.flink.FlinkStreamingTransformTranslators$ReadSourceTranslator.translateNode(FlinkStreamingTransformTranslators.java:336)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.flink.FlinkStreamingPipelineTranslator.applyStreamingTransform(FlinkStreamingPipelineTranslator.java:161)
....
    at Main.main(Main.java:6)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private final byte[] java.lang.String.value accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @2c34f934
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:172)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner.clean(ClosureCleaner.java:106)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private final byte[] java.lang.String.value accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @2c34f934
```

The error can be resolved by un-commenting the **Line-A** in the above `StreamReader.read()` method, but that method, `withMaxReadTime(...)` should not use other than for testing/demos as per the doc.

The pipeline instantiation done like this,

```
PipelineOptions pipelineOptions = PipelineOptionsFactory.create();
pipelineOptions.setRunner(FlinkRunner.class);
Pipeline pLine = Pipeline.create(pipelineOptions);
```

Questions:

1. Why this error occurs?
2. How do i solve this problem?

If possible, please provide some resources on this.

Answer (score 1):

The error appears to not be in Beam but in Flink's closure cleaner, which modifies private parts of user or SDK code. This appears to be a known issue with recent version of Java and Flink. See [Error message on example flink job: Unable to make field private final byte[] java.lang.String.value accessible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70814823/error-message-on-example-flink-job-unable-to-make-field-private-final-byte-ja)

Why does the commented line change things? Normally when reading from Kafka you read the stream in an *unbounded* read. When you specify `withMaxReadTime` this becomes a *bounded* read. So the translation to the underlying Flink operators is different.